# Cannot execute DLProf from NGC TensorFlow container

Tags: docker, nvidia, profiler

I would like to use dlprof command line utility.
According to the documentation:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/dlprof-user-guide/

I installed the nvidia tensorflow docker and I can run it
docker run --gpus all -it --rm -v local_dir:/root nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.03-tf2-py3

But I can neither execute dlprof nor find it.
Do you now how can I execute it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In NVIDIA containers dlprof is pre-installed and can be invoked through command line, as described in [quickstart](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/dlprof-user-guide/#quickstart_topic). It also shows you a great and easy way to view the results in tensorboard.

To get you started you can run dlprof by simply using

*dlprof [options] [your command]*

For example:

*dlprof --reports=summary python main.py*

Your code will be executed while being profiled by dlprof. The result will be put into dlprof_summary.csv in current directory. There are multiple kinds of reports available, such as: summary, detailed, kernel, tensor, etc.

More you can find at [report generation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/dlprof-user-guide/#report_generation)